# How to change opacity to Layout in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, opacity

Now i am going on with my screen background color changes while drag my image in (x,y)coordinates the layout should also change it opacity level of screen according to it.

I had went with tutorial below:

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/08/change-background-color-by-seekbar.html

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/02/animate-fade-infade-out-by-changing.html

Then tried it with by progrmatically setting as below:

**`layout.getBackground().setAlpha(30);`**

Here is the code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
public boolean status = false;
Button first,second;
LinearLayout layout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.trans);
first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first_theme);
second = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second_theme);
// if(status==true)
// {setTheme( android.R.style.ThemeFirst );
// }
// else
{
//            setTheme( android.R.style.ThemeSecond );
//        }
        first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
               status = true;
                layout.getBackground().setAlpha(30);
            }
        });

        second.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                second.getBackground().setAlpha(00);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But no it causes me `NullPointerException` error how can solve this if anyone have idea about this please help me friends.

Comment: please put your code.

Comment: Note that setAlpha takes a float value between 0 and 1, not 0-255

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setAlpha work on ,api +11 you can use some thing like this for every version:

```
 first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           status = true;
            AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.3f);
            alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
            alphaAnimation.setDuration(10);//duration in millisecond
            layout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
        }
 });
```

UPDATE:
  for getting back to original opacity you can do this:

```
AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.3f,1.0f);
alphaAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(10);
layout.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
```

Comment: What value should i set to get back to the orginal position.

how should show full transparency like android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" in alphaAnimation

Comment: AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f,0.3f); first argument is start opacity and second is end opacity. (1.0f means solid color, 0.0f means tranparent)

Comment: What parameter should i set to get back to the orginal position.